# Differences in padding on browsers

Tags: css, padding

I tried to ignore it initally, but its gotten up to a point where its fairly annoying. I have quite a few forms in my webiste and im applying a css padding of 3px for the submit buttons. They all look fine on Firefox, but none of these styling are applying to my safari browser. Any ideas on how to apply padding for the submit button in safari? Thanks

Comment: This probably doesn't have to do specifically with the submit button, but yet your other styles: `float`, `display`, etc.

Comment: can give any example in http://jsfiddle.net/ for understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using a "CSS reset" will do wonders for the consistency of your web style no matter which browsers you're interested in.  I have used the Yahoo [YUI CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) in the past, but there are many others which will also do more or less the same thing.  Your paragraphs, font sizes, paddings, margins, and much much more will work much more consistently with a CSS reset.

So what is it?  It's a stylesheet that sets most or all of the styles in your document to nil - it makes the document completely vanilla, but more importantly, *consistently* vanilla.  Then, all the styles you add afterwards are clean and consistent.  Try it, it's a huge time and effort saver for getting things consistent across browsers.